# How do I 'un-expand' so there aren't thousands of tiny paths?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path, images, image-trace

In illustrator, I hit 'expand' and deleted the white background of my vectorized image, but now that I've deleted what paths I wanted to delete, I want to get back to where I can adjust the image trace parameters of the whole image, not each tiny tile of the temple. [image: Here is my screen]

Comment: Did you try to Undo it? Or rasterized it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you `Expand` a Live Trace, the tracing options are no longer available.

There is *no way* to "go back" and edit the options used in tracing other than to `Undo` or start over.

If you  merely want to remove the white background when live tracing, tick the `Ignore White` option on the **Image Trace Panel** under the **Advanced Options**.

Comment: Cool, thank you! That 'ignore white' is great!